# How to 'call' my styled button(xaml) from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

I have a button in XAML which i styled the way I need it. This is XAML code of that button:

```
        <Button x:Name="btnAddNewItem"
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
            FontSize="15"
            BorderThickness="1.5"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="White"
            Background="White"
            BorderBrush="#0091EA" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="90" Width="90">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
```

And I would like to achieve something like this, so I would like to delete xaml button, and create same button programatically when its needed, with same style and everything like I did in xaml, example how I would like to create it:

```
 private void AddSubmenuButton(string name)
 {
            MyButton button = new MyButton();
            button.ButtonText = name;
 }
```

Is this possible and if so: how?

P.S I tried classic way, like this:

```
  Button a = new Button();
            a.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            a.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            a.BorderBrush = mySolidColorBrush;
            a.Content = "Button1";
            a.Width = 90;
            a.Height = 90;
```

But I get this:

[image]

It's possible to notice that thickness it not 1 at all, it has some weird value
and I don't know how to change it.. So that is reason why I created button in xaml which looks much more nice and I want to call it/create it from code behind.

**EDIT:**

**@mm8 THANK YOU A LOT!
THAT'S IT!**

This is awesome mate, but what about that If I would like to place icon + text in my button, I would ussualy
add something like this and its fine for me:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="80*">
    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="/MyProject.Wpf;component/Icons/customer-icon.png" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto"/>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Margin="0,0,0,3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >Izlaz</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

as you can see I would add Grid to my button and it would look like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btnAddNewItem"
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                    FontSize="15"
                    ToolTip="Podaci"
                    BorderThickness="1.5"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Background="White"
                    BorderBrush="#0091EA" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="90" Width="90">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
        <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80*">
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Source="/MyProject.Wpf;component/Icons/customer-icon.png" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto"/>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Margin="0,0,0,3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >Izlaz</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
                    </Button>
```

So could I somehow achieve this (image + text IN MY button ) also to create it programatically.

Comment: i don't know XAML and stuff, but i suspect you would like to execute sth. like `this.btnAddNewItem.Content = name`;

Comment: however, you should be more specific when it comes to explaining what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: @nozzleman I would like to delete/stop using xaml button, insted of that I would create same button, but this time programatically and only when its needed, with same style and everything like I did in xaml..

Comment: `I want to call it/create it from code behind` you do not want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a style in your App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="theStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <!-- and so on for each property...-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You can then apply this style to any Button in your application, either in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="btnAddNewItem" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
```

...or programmatically:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Style = Application.Current.Resources["myStyle"] as Style;
```

Comment: You could create the Grid, and also the Image and TextBlock, programmatically as well and set the Content property of the Button to it. But please ask a new question if you have a new issue. Make sure to describe your issue in detail.

Comment: I did as you said mate, here is example of what I tried and what I achieved acctualy, but still I'm stucked here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592928/how-to-add-grid-with-two-rows-and-a-content-to-a-button-programatically