# How to add Grid with two rows and a content to a Button programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, button, grid, styling

I created button in a XAML which contains image and text, I used Grid inside a button for that.
Here is my XAML code:

```
<Button x:Name="btnAddNewItem"
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                    FontSize="15"
                    BorderThickness="1.5"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="White"
                    Background="White"
                    BorderBrush="#0091EA" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="90" Width="90">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
        <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80*">
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Source="/MyProject.Wpf;component/Icons/customer-icon.png" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto"/>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Margin="0,0,0,3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >Customer</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
                    </Button>
```

Here is screenshoot of my button, and how that acctualy looks when my app is runned:

[image]

As you can see guys, **there are** image and text inside of my button.

Now I'm trying to make same-look button but from code behind and I achieved this (here is image):

[image]

It's almost the same button but It's missing image+text which should be placed in Grid ..

Here is my code :

```
 Image imgControl = new Image(); // place where I should keep my icon
 TextBlock text = new TextBlock(); // place where should be text below my icon

 imgControl.Source = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(uriSource) as ImageSource;
 text.Text = "Test text";

            string uriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Projects\MyProject.Wpf\Icons\customer-icon.png", UriKind.Relative).ToString();

            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
            mySolidColorBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#0091EA"));

            Button a = new Button();

            a.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            a.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            a.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            a.BorderBrush = mySolidColorBrush;
            a.Width  = 90;
            a.Height = 90;
            a.Style = Application.Current.Resources["MyButtonStyle"] as Style;

            Grid grid1=new Grid(); // I'm trying to add grid1 with two rows where I should place image and text, [row 0] for image, [row 1] for text
            RowDefinition rowImage = new RowDefinition(); //creating row one
            RowDefinition rowTitle = new RowDefinition(); //creating row two

            rowImage.Height = new GridLength(8.0, GridUnitType.Star); //Image will take 80% of space
            rowTitle.Height = new GridLength(2.0, GridUnitType.Star); //Text will take 20% of space

            grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(rowImage); //Adding image to row
            grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(rowTitle); //Adding text to row

            Grid.SetRow(imgControl, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(text, 1);

            a.Content = grid1;
```

As you can see, there is no image, neither text placed in my button, even if it looks like I added them to a grid which is added to my button.

So I guess I did something wrong with adding grid to a button..

Thanks guys,
Cheers

EDIT FOR Ed:

```
switch (buttonPurpose)
            {
                case SettingsSubmenuItemEnum.Test:
                    {
                        button.HasIcon = true;
                        button.Icon = Controls.Enumerations.IconType.Other;
                        button.Click += EH_testButton_Click;
                        button.IconAlignHorizontal = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                        button.TextAlignHorizontal = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                        break;
                    }

                case SettingsSubmenuItemEnum.Groups:
                    {
                        if (!OperatorController.HasOperatorAccess(currentOperator)
                            return;

                        button.HasIcon = true;
                        button.Icon = Controls.Enumerations.IconType.Grupe;
                        button.Click += EH_SubmenuButtonClickGrupePromet;
                        button.IconAlignHorizontal = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                        button.TextAlignHorizontal = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                        break;
                    }

                case SettingsSubmenuItemEnum.Cities:
                    {
                        if (!OperatorController.HasOperatorPristup(currentOperator))
                            return;

                        button.HasIcon = true;
                        button.Icon = Controls.Enumerations.IconType.Other;
                        button.Click += EH_MjestaClick;
                        button.IconAlignHorizontal = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                        button.TextAlignHorizontal = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                        break;
                    }

 spContentSubmenu.Children.Add(button);
}
}
```

In code above I'm checking which button user clicked and by that I'm showing to him corresponding buttons..

variable `buttonpurpose` is `SettingsSubmenuItemEnum` type

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: <RowDefinition Height="80*"> you have a typo
<RowDefinition Height="80*" />

Comment: @EdPlunkett because I have a menu on top of screen (not visible right now), and that menu is acctualy 5 buttons placed in a stack panel, and each button mean something, for example, when you click on first button called Customer, it should generate 4 new buttons, for example, ADD NEW CUSTOMER, CHECK CUSTOMER ROLES, SEE INACTIVE CUSTOMERS and so on..  thats reason why I need to create this kind of button programatically...

Comment: Use a template. Don't waste your time on this.

Comment: Why do you need to create the button programmatically? Also, every time I see somebody say "u gimme", my interest in helping drops by 50%.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I need to generate different btn on different click, lets say Menu contains 2 btn, one for articles, another one for customers,
When user clicks on articles from top menu, on the bottom of screen options should be changed, so if user clicks on articles,
on bottom I would should 3 buttons, ADD NEW ARTICLE, SEE ALL ARTICLES, SEE ALL GROUP ARTICLES for example..
If user click on CUSTOMERS after that,that buttons should be hidden and another buttons should be shown, ADD CUSTOMER, 
SEE ALL CUSTOMERS etc,and I'm achieving this by creating btns progr., by add or rem them from stack p.

Comment: @EdPlunkett why your interest drops by 50%. I'm sorry mate, I did not want you to feel like that, I'm sorry..

Comment: In WPF the most straightforward way to do that is by creating all of the buttons in XAML and doing their image/whatever content stuff using templates. Then you'd show or hide groups of buttons as needed. Anyway, though, it sounds like you've already got a substantial investment in doing it the wrong way, and I think mm8's answer probably just identified the specific issue you have right now. Next project, read up on MVVM first, it's much easier.

Comment: @EdPlunkett By following your comment, if we are talking about 4 buttons per one menu item for example ARTICLES,
than I would create 4 buttons in XAML, and also 4 for CUSTOMERS and also 4 for anything else from main menu,
and what I would do is acctauly changing their visibility state? I thought my code would be cleaner if I do like this,
One button and call it when needed.. check for edit there I will post what I'm doing right now.. and it looks like it's not bad approach :/ but as you said probably I'm not thinking in a wpf direction yet as much as I should..

Comment: If you put each group of buttons in its own stackpanel, and bind each stackpanel's visibility to a viewmodel property, it's pretty clean on the viewmodel end. That's not really the Right MVVM Way To Do It, but going full MVVM would probably be a major redesign at this point.

Comment: @EdPlunkett because I had enought free time, I did as you said, each group has own stack panel, when button is triggered stackpanel with buttons is shown, when another button is triggered this stackpanel is hidden, another one is shown and so on :) So "I must" avoid creation of my WPF CONTROLS in CODE BEHIND - C#. "I must" allways do it with XAML :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I guess I did something wrong with adding grid to a button..

You need to add the Image and the TextBlock to the Grid's Children collection:

```
...
Grid.SetRow(imgControl, 0);
Grid.SetRow(text, 1);

//ADD:
grid1.Children.Add(imgControl);
grid1.Children.Add(text);

a.Content = grid1;
```